# How to not to execute a script on IE8 or older?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a function that calls many functions which are not supported by IE8, so I am looking for how to disable executing this script for IE8. I saw many solutions like using HTML comments:

```
<!--[if !IE]> --> Code <!-- <![endif]--><!--[if IE]>
```

But I want disabling IE8 interpretation inside a function, because there are other scripts that run correctly on IE8.

There is a function in jQuery "jQuery.browser()" but it has been deprecated.

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use feature detection, not browser sniffing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE 8/) == null) {
  // do something !IE8
}
```

from:

[how do I run a script only for IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067999/how-do-i-run-a-script-only-for-ie-8)

[Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: And what if I want to not to run this on IE8 and older? should I change the match parameter?

Comment: You have an example in the second link. the comment noted 28

Comment: Or
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-prior-to-v9-in-javascript